# Is it possible to set different settings for different request in the same Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, crawlera

I want to use Crawlera only for some requests in a Scrapy spider. So I want to set `CRAWLERA_ENABLED` differently for different requests. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `dont_proxy` key in `meta` for those requests you don't want to use Crawlera. E.g.

```
# Supposing you have crawlera enabled in `settings.py`
yield scrapy.Request(
    url, 
    meta={"dont_proxy": True}, 
    callback=self.parse
)
```

Comment: Once I use `dont_proxy`, it won't set Crawlera when I retry a request

Comment: `scrapy-crawlera` checks if the key exists in `meta` [(link to the code)](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-crawlera/blob/13a893f940254629a6bb2ef7d70ed887c240278b/scrapy_crawlera/middleware.py#L177). Try to remove `dont_proxy` from `meta` instead of setting it into `False`.

Comment: Yup, that's what happened when I check `scrapy-crawlera`'s code.